# Catch exceptions due to parentheses/brackets/braces mismatch in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, error-handling

The following is the code to evaluate Excel formulae using Ruby. Only `SUM` function is shown here. I implemented this function in two languages `Ruby` and `Python`

### Python 3.10.0

```py
def SUM(a,b):
    return a+b
for i in range(int(input())):
    s=input()
    if s[0]!="=":
        print("INVALID")
    else:
        try:
            print(eval(s.replace('=','')))
         except:
            print("INVALID")
```

### Ruby 3.0.2

```rb
def SUM a,b
    a+b
end

gets
puts $<.map{
    if !_1[/^=/]
        :INVALID
    else
        eval(_1.tr(?=,'')) rescue :INVALID
    end
}
```

Consider the following inputs

### Input 1

```
4
=SUM(8, 99)
=SUM(343, -b1)
=SUM(-8,  -99)
=SUM(101 , -25) + 6
```

### Input 2

```
3
SUM(4, 1)
=SUM(5, 1
=SuM(2, 1)
```

For Input 1 both Ruby and Python codes work perfectly. They both catch the error `b1` not defined and hence go to `except` or `rescue`

But for input 2, only Python code works perfectly while Ruby fails to catch the error `)` missing (in 3rd line). It doesn't go to `rescue`. I tried using `begin` and `resuce` too. But nothing. How to rescue these kind of errors in Ruby?

Comment: Also I don't see how this helps in "evaluating EXCEL formulas"

Comment: I wanted to ask how to simulate `try` and `except` exactly as in Pyton

Comment: It's not the `try/except`, the actual "problem" is why `eval` in ruby does not raise error as you expect. I'm not familiar with Ruby, but that's what you should ask.

Comment: Your Ruby code is making my eyes bleed. Can you please format it properly? After that, maybe explain what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

in ruby `rescue` by default only rescues subclasses of `StandardError`. This works for most cases, because most stuff that you would want to rescue is a descendant of that class (`NoMethodError`, `RuntimeError`, `ArgumentError` and so on), and most stuff that you don't want to rescue (`NoMemoryError`, `SyntaxError`, `SystemExit` and so on) are not.

In your case, `eval("SUM(5, 1")` is missing a parentheses. It's a syntax error and ruby raises `SyntaxError`. Your `rescue` is looking for `StandardError`, which `SyntaxError` is not.

You could rescue all standard errors + syntax error or rescue all `Exception`s, but do note that if you do rescue all `Exception`s, then your program might be difficult to exit.

`ctrl+c` is `Interrupt`, which is a subclass of `Exception` and can be rescued.

`kill` on the process is a `SignalException`, which is a subclass of `Exception` and can be rescued.

```
begin
  eval(_1.tr(?=,''))
rescue StandardError, SyntaxError
  :INVALID
end
```

or

```
begin
  eval(_1.tr(?=,''))
rescue Exception # I strongly advise against this
  :INVALID
end
```